# Moving jpg's using powershell script with variable directories

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I am writing a scheduled script that will move images (jpg's) from one location to another. 
The problem is that a parent directory is variable in name while the end directory is fixed.

If robocopy would do this I would be happy:  robocopy C:\temp\pcbmodel**\defect c:\test**\defect*. But it doesn't

For example this will almost work:

```
foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem C:\temp\pcbmodel\*\*\defect -recurse)
{
if ($i.CreationTime -lt ($(Get-Date).AddMonths(0)))
{
    write $i.FullName
    Copy-Item $i.FullName C:\Test
}
}
```

The problem is that the files are copied in c:\test but the  ** path isn't. And the * path I need as it will change for each customer.

Some suggestions would be nice,
Bert

Comment: What exactly prevents you from doing `robocopy C:\temp\pcbmodel C:\test *.jpg /s`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should put you on the right path to getting a working solution. The important part is the Resolve-Path cmdlet which takes a -Relative parameter: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849858.aspx. new-Item -Force merely tell it to create a folder structure if required.

```
# $OldRoot = 'Top-level of old files'
# $DestRoot = 'Top-level of destination'
# Go to old root so relative paths are correct
Set-Location $OldRoot
# Get all the images, then for each one...
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include "*.jpeg", "*.jpg" | 
ForEach-Object { 
        # Save full name to avoid issues later
        $Source = $_.FullName

        # Construct destination filename using relative path and destination root
        $Destination = '{0}\{1}' -f $DestRoot, (Resolve-Path -Relative -Path:$Source).TrimStart('.\')

        # If new destination doesn't exist, create it
        If(-Not (Test-Path ($DestDir = Split-Path -Parent -Path:$Destination))) { 
            New-Item -Type:Directory -Path:$DestDir -Force -Verbose 
        }

        # Copy old item to new destination
        Copy-Item -Path:$Source -Destination:$Destination -Verbose
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I cannot get this working. Some additional help. I don't know how to seperate the root from the original source. Please explain  '{0}\{1}' -f $DestinationRoot, (Resolve-Path -Relative -Path $_). Thank you

Comment: It's the powershell string formatter; https://devcentral.f5.com/blogs/us/powershell-abcs-f-is-for-format-operator has a good explanation.

Comment: thanks. Now i only need to remove the . ? Any idea? PS C:\temp> C:\Temp\test3.ps1
c:\test\.\pcbmodel\help1\help2\defect
c:\test\.\pcbmodel\help1\help2\defect\t.jpg

Comment: Hi, I now got this error: Resolve-Path : Cannot find path 'C:\test\pcbmodel\help1\help2\defect\t.jpg' because it does not exist.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\test\pcbmode...p2\defect\t.jpg:String) [Resolve-Path], At C:\Temp\test5.ps1:14 char:61
+     If(-Not (Test-Path ($DestDir = Split-Path -Parent -Path:$DestItem))) {
+                                                             ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Split-Path], .. It is making the path correct but not creating the directory when it doesn't exist. If you can have a look please!

Comment: Resolve-Path appears to only work on items that already exist. Anyway, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like that:

```
$step1 = get-childitem  C:\temp\pcbmodel\
$Else = #FILETYPE YOU DO NOT WANT
$step1 | foreach {get-childitem -recurse -exclude "Directories", $ELSE | where {$_.Creationtime -lt ($(get-date).Addmonths(0))} 
                 }
```

Hope I got it right and this helps :)

EDIT: Work with **-Exclude** and **-Include** parameters they help a lot :)

EDIT2: Ofc, I overread something, sorry for the many edits - you are just looking for jpg files.

```
$step1 | foreach {get-childitem -recurse -include *.jpg, *.jpeg | where {$_.Creationtime -lt ($(get-date).Addmonths(0))}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, but the problem is not to get the files, but to put them in a corresponding directory. So original the map can be: c:\temp\pcbmodel\customerA\Files\Defect\images.jpg. it need to be moved to d:\archive\pcbmodel\customerA\Files\Defect\images.jpg. I cannot get the files in a different directory maintaining the original path... let me know if its clear (or not). thanks!

Comment: added a new answere, because it is completely different to this one. hope this helps now :)

Answer (score 0):

Another idea:
Don't try it on your **C: disk**. It will need forever. But if u have permissions for every directory and subdirectory in a certain path and the subdirectory amount is not enormous it should work.

I created a directory "New Directory" on C: and another "New Directory" in this directory. And ofc, another "New Directory" in the directory. and lastly I created a file with the name "superduper.txt" --> C:\New Directory\New Directory\New Directory\superduper.txt

```
(get-childitem C:\).FullName | where {(Get-ChildItem $_).FullName | where {(get-childitem $_ -Recurse).FullName -match "superduper"}}
```

Result:

```
C:\New Directory
```

I think it won't be fast and you would need 2 of these to achieve your goal, I guess it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to copy all subfolders and their files from one folder into another, without copying their parent folder as well.

For example, in `C:\test` with some subfolders containing files, copy to `D:\test` without it being `D:\test\test\subfolders`.