# Copy-item Files in Folders and subfolders in the same directory structure of source server using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am struggling really hard to get this below script worked to copy the files in folders and sub folders in the proper structure (As the source server).

Lets say, there are folders mentioned below:

Main Folder: File aaa, File bbb

Sub Folder a: File 1, File 2, File 3

Sub Folder b: File 4, File 5, File 6

Script used:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path \\Server1\Test -recurse | ForEach-Object {
Copy-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Destination \\server2\test |
Get-Acl -Path $_.FullName | Set-Acl -Path "\\server2\test\$(Split-Path -Path $_.FullName -Leaf)"

}
```

Output:
File aaa, File bbb

Sub Folder a (Empty Folder)

Sub Folder b (Empty Folder)

File 1, File 2, File 3, File 4, File 5, File 6.

I want the files to get copied to their respective folders (Like the source folders). Any further help is highly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to copy everything, Kevin_'s answer should work. If you need to filter the input, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788208/moving-jpgs-using-powershell-script-with-variable-directories

Comment: @Kevin_ full sample using **robocopy** in powershell ?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

This can be done just using Copy-Item.  No need to use Get-Childitem.  I think you are just overthinking it.

```
Copy-Item -Path C:\MyFolder -Destination \\Server\MyFolder -recurse -Force
```

I just tested it and it worked for me.

**edit:** *included suggestion from the comments*

```
# Add wildcard to source folder to ensure consistent behavior
Copy-Item -Path $sourceFolder\* -Destination $targetFolder -Recurse
```

Comment: I've found that the behaviour of this command changes if you run it more than once. The first time, it will copy everything to \\Server\MyFolder. The second and subsequent times, it will copy everything to \\Server\MyFolder\MyFolder

Comment: @thecodefish I noticed this too but only happens if the target directory doesn't exist. Using New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $target -Force | Out-Null will solve the issue. -Force switch will create the directory only if it doesn't exist and Out-Null will not pollute your output.

Comment: Also works with pattern matching like `Copy-Item **/*.txt -Destination C:/destination`

Comment: @thecodefish Old post, but this issue is still relevant.  If a wildcard is added to the `-Path`,  it will end up in the `-Destination` (instead of \\Server\MyFolder\MyFolder).  I ended up with `Copy-Item "$PathToCopy\*" -Destination "$Destination" -Recurse`

Comment: @Indy411 Do you mean `Copy-Item C:\Users\sranade\Desktop\TestFolderSource -Destination New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path C:\TestFodlerDestination -Force | Out-Null -Recurse` like this? It doesn't work for me.

Comment: @thecodefishHow can one overcome this issue? can you provide the exact script?

Comment: @Sameer run New-Item to create the directory before you run Copy-Item

Comment: @Indy411 I want to run the following script every day `New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path C:\TestFodlerDestination -Force | Out-Null
Copy-Item C:\Users\sranade\Desktop\TestFolderSource -Destination C:\TestFodlerDestination -Recurse`, but when I executed it for the 2nd time, it gave an error `Copy-Item : An item with the specified name C:\TestFodlerDestination\TestFolderSource already exists.
At C:\Script\test.ps1:2 char:1`

Comment: I had a directory structure that looked like this: ./web.config, ./bin/*, ./dll/* ... the issue I saw with `Copy-Item -Path "$sourceFolder\*" -Destination $targetFolder -Recurse` was that it seemed to take everything under the subdirectories in $sourceFolder ( in my case dll and bin), and put it under the root of $targetFolder along with all the other files copied from the root of sourceFolder. This behavior was also fixed by creating $targetFolder before doing the recursive copy. Microsoft: This is not sensible or sane behavior.

Comment: I found using `-Container` seems to get the job done.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to mirror same content from source to destination, try following one.

```
function CopyFilesToFolder ($fromFolder, $toFolder) {
    $childItems = Get-ChildItem $fromFolder
    $childItems | ForEach-Object {
         Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $toFolder -Recurse -Force
    }
}
```

Test:

```
CopyFilesToFolder "C:\temp\q" "c:\temp\w"
```

Answer (score 2):

one time i found this script, this copy folder and files and keep the same structure of the source in the destination, you can make some tries with this.

```
# Find the source files
$sourceDir="X:\sourceFolder"

# Set the target file
$targetDir="Y:\Destfolder\"
Get-ChildItem $sourceDir -Include *.* -Recurse |  foreach {

    # Remove the original  root folder
    $split = $_.Fullname  -split '\\'
    $DestFile =  $split[1..($split.Length - 1)] -join '\' 

    # Build the new  destination file path
    $DestFile = $targetDir+$DestFile

    # Move-Item won't  create the folder structure so we have to 
    # create a blank file  and then overwrite it
    $null = New-Item -Path  $DestFile -Type File -Force
    Move-Item -Path  $_.FullName -Destination $DestFile -Force
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble with the most popular answer (overthinking).  It put AFolder in the \Server\MyFolder\AFolder and I wanted the contents of AFolder and below in MyFolder.  This didn't work.

```
Copy-Item -Verbose -Path C:\MyFolder\AFolder -Destination \\Server\MyFolder -recurse -Force
```

Plus I needed to Filter and only copy *.config files.

This didn't work, with "\*" because it did not recurse

```
Copy-Item -Verbose -Path C:\MyFolder\AFolder\* -Filter *.config -Destination \\Server\MyFolder -recurse -Force
```

I ended up lopping off the beginning of the path string, to get the childPath relative to where I was recursing from.  This works for the use-case in question and went down many subdirectories, which some other solutions do not.

```
Get-Childitem -Path "$($sourcePath)/**/*.config" -Recurse | 
ForEach-Object {
  $childPath = "$_".substring($sourcePath.length+1)
  $dest = "$($destPath)\$($childPath)" #this puts a \ between dest and child path
  Copy-Item -Verbose -Path $_ -Destination $dest -Force   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
Function Backup-Files {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [System.IO.FileInfo[]]$Source,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String]$Destination
    )

    if (!(Test-Path $Destination)) {[void][System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory($Destination)}

    ForEach ($File in $Source) {
        $SourceRoot = $(Convert-Path $File.PSParentPath).split('\')[0]
        $NewFile    = $($File.FullName).Replace($SourceRoot,$Destination)
        $NewDir     = $($File.DirectoryName).Replace($SourceRoot,$Destination)
        [void][System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory($NewDir)
        Copy-Item -Path $File.FullName -Destination $NewFile -Force
    }
}
```

Examples

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Copy FileInfo object or array to a new destination while retaining the original directory structure.
.PARAMETER Source
    FileInfo object or array. (Get-Item/Get-ChildItem)
.PARAMETER Destination
    Path to backup source data to.
.NOTES
    Version (Date):             1.0 (2023-02-04)
    Author:                     Joshua Biddle (thebiddler@gmail.com)
    Purpose/Change:             Initial script development.
    Known Bugs:                 
.EXAMPLE
    Backup-Files -Source $(Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\*\Documents' -Recurse -Force -Exclude 'My Music','My Pictures','My Videos','desktop.ini' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -Destination "C:\Temp\UserBackup"
.EXAMPLE
    Backup-Files -Source $(Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\*\Desktop' -Exclude "*.lnk","desktop.ini" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -Destination "C:\Temp\UserBackup"
#>
```

Answer (score -1):

I wanted a solution to copy files modified after a certain date and time which mean't I need to use Get-ChildItem piped through a filter. Below is what I came up with:

```
$SourceFolder = "C:\Users\RCoode\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyProject"
$ArchiveFolder = "J:\Temp\Robin\Deploy\MyProject"
$ChangesStarted = New-Object System.DateTime(2013,10,16,11,0,0)
$IncludeFiles = ("*.vb","*.cs","*.aspx","*.js","*.css")

Get-ChildItem $SourceFolder -Recurse -Include $IncludeFiles | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt $ChangesStarted} | ForEach-Object {
    $PathArray = $_.FullName.Replace($SourceFolder,"").ToString().Split('\') 

    $Folder = $ArchiveFolder

    for ($i=1; $i -lt $PathArray.length-1; $i++) {
        $Folder += "\" + $PathArray[$i]
        if (!(Test-Path $Folder)) {
            New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $Folder
        }
    }   
    $NewPath = Join-Path $ArchiveFolder $_.FullName.Replace($SourceFolder,"")

    Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $NewPath  
}
```