# Insufficient memory in Windows command line

Tags: batch-file, cmd, buffer, pkzip

I created a batch file which copies a directory with xcopy for backup reasons. Then I use pkzip in order to zip the backup folder (and email it through a batch file which is working), but I am getting an error message for insufficient memory. I tried to increase the buffer size in command line properties but it didn't work. I also tried to increase the number of buffers but it didn't work either. Any thoughts/solutions?

The reason I am doing this backup routine is that I want these tasks to be automatically done through Windows scheduled tasks.

Comment: So which command gives the error? Please [edit] your question to include your batch file and tell us which line gives the error.

Comment: pkzip -spwd -x*.bat 2014 -rp -&, is the command and the error(35) is : Insufficient memory. But the strange thing is that i tested in 3 different computers and it worked like a charm in 2 of them, even for bigger files(>15MB). But in the third one it doesn't stabilize and sometimes it pops out the error but sometimes not. I guess that folders and long sub folders may be the problem due to the size of characters, but it's just an assumption.

Comment: What version (and bitness) of Windows? What version of `pkzip`? If I can understand your `pkzip` statement: no operation defined (like `-add`); `-spwd`=scramble with password; `-x*.bat`=exclude batch files `2014`=archive name `-rp`=recurse subdirectories and store paths; `-&`=??? Maybe some kind of recursive definition imposed in it: archive `2004` file into itself?

Comment: Use powershell like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842764/copy-item-files-in-folders-and-subfolders-in-the-same-directory-structure-of-sou

Answer (score 26):

I too got this error : `Insufficient memory`. I found a relevant answer at this link : https://web.archive.org/web/20070214005534/http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2007/02/05/xcopy-insufficient-memory/

> It appears that this message shows up when the fully qualified (ie.
> with path) name of the copied file is longer than 254 characters which
> seems to be Windows maximum path length.
>
> In conclusion: [xxcopy](http://www.xxcopy.com/xcpywhat.htm) works, but robocopy works even better.

Finally my batch file looks like this

```
@echo off
ROBOCOPY "H:\Laptop-Backup" "E:\Laptop-Backup" /s

rem /e: Include directories and sub directories even if empty
REM /s Copy Subdirectories, but not empty ones.
```

Comment: ROBOCOPY is better than XCOPY! But RSYNC is better than ROBOCOPY and 4 years later we have windows subsystem linux so we can run it on windows now. Just FYI.

Comment: Commenting on @gunslingor's recommendation to use rsync within WSL Linux. It works, and you get everything that comes with rsync. But, I got a significant performance drop. Windows defender (antimalware) feels the need to scan every file being copied using rsync but not xcopy / robocopy. With my external hdd, xcopy gives me 180MBps, rsync drops to 15MBps.

Comment: Finally I found a good reason to switch from using `xcopy` all the times to using `robocopy` all the times. Thank you for bringing this limitation to my attention. I would never guess the "insufficient memory" alone.

Answer (score 3):

The standard Windows command line tools like xcopy, rmdir cannot operate with paths longer than MAX_PATH(260 chars). If you want to remove the directory which contains such file which full path is longer than MAX_PATH, or if you want to copy recursively a directory to such a place where the full path to at least one of its files would be longer than MAX_PATH then these command line tools fail.

However you can bypass it with "**move**" command line tool, because in distinct to xcopy and rmdir(rd) it seems to not iterating the files in the directory one-by-one.
This workaround may be not always convenient and requires additional actions, but for the automation/scripting purpose I don't see any other way if you cannot or don't want using special tools a.k.a robocopy. This way works with a directory, but not with a single file. Let me show an example.

Create a directory. Path length: 245 chars

```
E:\>mkdir E:\veryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooongdirectory
```

Thy to create a file inside it so that the file path length is bigger than MAX_PATH. Usual way it won't work.

```
E:\>echo "content" > E:\veryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooongdirectory\longlonglonglonglongfilename.txt
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Workaround: Create a file(s) with a short path and move the directory containing the file(s) into the long path.

```
E:\>echo "content" > somedir\longlonglonglonglongfilename.txt

E:\>move somedir E:\veryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooongdirectory\
        1 dir(s) moved.
```

Check 1: Was the directory completely moved (with all files)? - Yes.

```
E:\>dir E:\veryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooongdirectory\somedir
 Volume in drive E is Workspace
 Volume Serial Number is C864-7C96

 Directory of E:\veryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooongdirectory\somedir

08/09/2019  11:52 AM    <DIR>          .
08/09/2019  11:52 AM    <DIR>          ..
08/09/2019  11:52 AM                12 longlonglonglonglongfilename.txt
               1 File(s)             12 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  130,574,221,312 bytes free
```

Check 2. The path is really longer than MAX_PATH, that's why it won't be accessible by the full path for the usual command line tools, so we did everything correct:

```
E:\>dir E:\veryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooongdirectory\somedir\longlonglonglonglongfilename.txt
 Volume in drive E is Workspace
 Volume Serial Number is C864-7C96

 Directory of E:\veryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooongdirectory\somedir

File Not Found
```

The same workaround is valid if you want to remove (with rmdir) the directory containing subfolders/files whose path is longer than MAX_PATH. Just move the upper directory to some short temporary location and there you can rmdir it.

NOTE: Windows command line tool "move" can move directories only within the same disk letter.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was that xcopy was trying to copy files with very long filenames inside a particular directory (call it /Documents/LongNames) containing lots of these types of names.  Because the files with the long names all went together in my case, I zipped the Documents/LongNames sub-directory to a single zip file, since I do not use it often.  The backup with xcopy of all of my files in /Documents works just fine now.
In general a good way to debug a big batch xcopy is to have your batch file make a log of the files that it is copying.  So when there is an issue, it is easier to find. This is how I found the issue to begin with.